# How to execute (batch *.clp (JESS)) from command/ .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, jess, clp

Basically i opened jess.bat then passed  (batch a.clp) it works because it must.

But how to make file .bat? which will open jess.bat and then execute line:

PS
i'v tried everything
and i found other way by putting a.clp in file jess.bat:
%RUN_JAVA% -classpath ".;%JESS_HOME%\lib\jess.jar;%JESS_HOME%\lib\jsr94.jar;%CLASSPATH%" jess.Main %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 **"path"/a.clp**

Answer (score 0):

You should consult some tutorial on "redirection" in cmd, Windows' command interpreter.

You can, in the .bat file you intend to write, call

```
jess.bat <command.txt
```

where command.txt contains one line:

```
(batch a.clp)
```

Another option is to write, in the .bat file

```
echo "(batch a.clp)" | jess.bat
```

In this form, you can substitute a vtch file parameter expansion in place of the literal `a.clp`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something called the CALL command.

Your question is very unclear. This script will open Jess.bat, but you don't specify which command you want to run, Here goes...

So you would make two .bat's! Look here!

First one:

@echo off

Call file.bat

quit

Second one:

Call Jess.bat.

quit

You only have to run the first one, then the second one will run automatically.

Please be more specific with your question next time, or make an edit, so I can help solve your problem!

GL!- Logan